# Adding ORCHARD CMS functionality in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have a project in mvc 4 that's really huge. Now I want to include Orchard CMS functionality into it.

I don't want it to do the other way round by including my MVC 4 project as a part of Orchard since its way too big. Would rather like to include Orchard as a CMS module in it.

What I have done so far:
1. downloaded the orchard source zip file from codeplex.
2. included it as a separate solution in my existing mvc 4 project

Now I want this orchard module to communicate with my mvc 4 project, like placing in a link on of the pages of my web project which would redirect to showing the content which is managed by the Orchard CMS system.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Orchard has not been designed for that. I would say the feasibility of this is: nearly impossible to extremely difficult. I'd say your best bet is to have Orchard live in a separate application and limit interaction with what you can do with links and web/rest services.

Comment: Any other proposed solution? I want my project to have a subfolder like CMS where all the CMS content will be present along with redirections to my CMS pages from any of the projects pages. Any other CMS which allows such integration for MVC projects?

Comment: You can try Umbraco. I think they support that sort of scenario.

Comment: There's one called Piranha CMS which is better designed to be added to an existing solutions, though it's not fully featured by any means.